# How do i get more tickets in dream house days?

Tags: dream-house-days

I love playing dream house days but the tickets are VERY rare, i dont want to pay with real money, how do j get more tickets but without paying for them? I wilm be grateful for all the tips and tricks and even advice i get, i would like to move my tenant but i cannot because i only have 2 tickets.